# 2D array comparison and output file problem | python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get compare two different unequal 2D array, 
Array1: (RNA sequence) [63:3]

```
AAA
AAC
AGC
UAC
```

Array2: RNA_coordinate_source_file [128:11]

```
ATOM    142 H1' A   5   -1.227  8.932   12.229  1.00    0.00    H
ATOM    142 H1' A   5   -1.227  8.932   12.229  1.00    0.00    H
ATOM    142 H1' G   5   -1.227  8.932   12.229  1.00    0.00    H
ATOM    143 N1  G   5   -0.447  7.106   12.630  1.00    0.00    N
ATOM    143 N1  G   5   -0.447  7.106   12.630  1.00    0.00    N
ATOM    143 N1  C   5   -0.447  7.106   12.630  1.00    0.00    N
ATOM    142 H1' C   5   -1.227  8.932   12.229  1.00    0.00    H
ATOM    143 N1  G   5   -0.447  7.106   12.630  1.00    0.00    N
ATOM    143 N1  G   5   -0.447  7.106   12.630  1.00    0.00    N
ATOM    143 N1  C   5   -0.447  7.106   12.630  1.00    0.00    N
```

I want to write a new file when RNA sequences(array1) are whatever the triplet and a new file is with the corresponding name like AAG.pdb and with all the line that has column 4th(s) corresponding to AAG coordinate.

out file should extract all the lines from array2, and then file will have all the coordinate for "A",  then again A and G, like wise for all the triples, separate file and separate name.

I found that unequal arrays cannot be compared and my following code does not work,
I need help thank you

```
import re
with open("drive/My Drive/RES/dimeric_force_field/Test/python_read/cropped.pdb", "r") as file:
            arr = [ re.split("[ \t\r\n]+", line)[:-1] for line in file ]
            #re.split("[ \t\r\n]+", line)[:-1]

          #print ("pdb file as array=",arr)
          #print("lenght=",len(arr))

fw = open("drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/pdb_out.pdb", "w")

myArray = ["A", "C", "G", "U"]
triplet = []
for a1 in myArray:
  for a2 in myArray:
    for a3 in myArray:
      triplet.append(a1+a2+a3)

print("triplets=",triplet)
print("triplet array length=",len(triplet))
print("arr=",arr)
print("triplet array length=",len(arr))

i = 64
while i < len(triplet):
      s1 = triplet[i][0] #U
      s2 = triplet[i][1] #U
      s3 = triplet[i][2] #G
      #print (srt(i)+' '+s1+' '+s2+' '+s3)
      #print (s1+' '+s2+' '+s

      j= 0      
      while j < (len(arr)-1):
            el1 = arr[j][0] # line_def
            el2 = arr[j][1] # atom_no
            el3 = arr[j][2] # atom_name
            el4 = arr[j][3] # residue_name
            el5 = arr[j][4] # residure_no
            el6 = arr[j][5] # x
            el7 = arr[j][6] # y
            el8 = arr[j][7] # z
            el9 = arr[j][8] #
            el10 = arr[j][9] #
            el11 = arr[j][10] #
            #print (str(j)+'\t'+el1+'\t'+el2+'\t'+el3+'\t'+el4+'\t'+el5+'\t'+el6+'\t'+el7+'\t'+el8+'\t'+el9+'\t'+el10+'\t'+el11)
            #print (str(j)+'\t'+line_def+'\t'+atom_no+'\t'+atom_name+'\t'+residue_name+'\t'+residure_no+'\t'+x+'\t'+y+'\t'+z+'\t'+el9+'\t'+el10+'\t'+el11)

            if s1==el4:
                #print(str(i)+" "+str(j)+" "+"slected=","\t".join(arr[j]))
                print("\t".join(arr[j]))
                fw.write(str(i)+ "    "+ str(j) +  "\t".join(arr[j])+'\n')

            if s2==el4:
                #print(str(i)+" "+str(j)+" "+"slected=","\t".join(arr[j]))
                print("\t".join(arr[j]))
                fw.write(str(i)+"    " + str(j) +  "\t".join(arr[j])+'\n')

            if s3==el4:
                #a= print(str(i)+" "+str(j)+" "+"slected=","\t".join(arr[j]))
                print("\t".join(arr[j]))
                fw.write(str(i) +"    "+ str(j) + "\t".join(arr[j])+'\n')

            #fw.write("\t".join(arr[j])
            #fw.write(p2)
            #fw.write(p3)
            j+=1
      i+=1

fw.write("TER")
fw.close()

fr=open("drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/pdb_out.pdb", "r")
print(fr.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working,

```
while i < len(triplet) :  # goes to 0 t 63


      fw = open("drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/test/"+str(triplet[i])+".pdb", "w")  # 
      #fw = open("drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/test/str(triplet[i])+".pdb", "w")

      if s1=="A":
        fw.write(    (   '\n'.join(    [   '\t'.join(   [  str(Y) for Y in lines]    )   for lines in NUC_A  ]    )    )    )   # no '\n' in frst set because it avoid first line of the pdb file
        n1="A"
      elif s1=="C":
        fw.write(    (     '\n'.join(    [   '\t'.join(   [  str(Y) for Y in lines]    )   for lines in NUC_C  ]    )    )   )
        n1="C"
      elif s1=="G":
        fw.write(    (     '\n'.join(    [   '\t'.join(   [  str(Y) for Y in lines]    )   for lines in NUC_G  ]    )    )   )
        n1="G"
      else: #print U
        fw.write(    (     '\n'.join(    [   '\t'.join(   [  str(Y) for Y in lines]    )   for lines in NUC_U  ]    )    )   )
        n1="G"  
      #fw.write('\n'+str(i)+' '+"s1 END"+'\n')


      if s2=="A":
        fw.write( '\n' + (     '\n'.join(    [   '\t'.join(   [  str(Y) for Y in lines]    )   for lines in NUC_A  ]    )    )   )
        n2="A" 
      elif s2=="C":
        fw.write( '\n' + (     '\n'.join(    [   '\t'.join(   [  str(Y) for Y in lines]    )   for lines in NUC_C  ]    )    )   )
        n2="C"
      elif s2=="G":
        fw.write( '\n' + (     '\n'.join(    [   '\t'.join(   [  str(Y) for Y in lines]    )   for lines in NUC_G  ]    )    )   )
        n2=""
      else: #print U
        fw.write( '\n' + (     '\n'.join(    [   '\t'.join(   [  str(Y) for Y in lines]    )   for lines in NUC_U  ]    )    )   )

      #fw.write('\n'+str(i)+' '+"s2 END"+'\n')


      if s3=="A":
        fw.write( '\n' + (     '\n'.join(    [   '\t'.join(   [  str(Y) for Y in lines]    )   for lines in NUC_A  ]    )    )   )

      elif s3=="C":
        fw.write( '\n' + (     '\n'.join(    [   '\t'.join(   [  str(Y) for Y in lines]    )   for lines in NUC_C  ]    )    )   )

      elif s3=="G":
        fw.write( '\n' + (     '\n'.join(    [   '\t'.join(   [  str(Y) for Y in lines]    )   for lines in NUC_G  ]    )    )   )

      else: #print U
        fw.write( '\n' + (     '\n'.join(    [   '\t'.join(   [  str(Y) for Y in lines]    )   for lines in NUC_U  ]    )    )   )

      #fw.write('\n'+str(i)+' '+"s3 END"+'\n')



      fw.close() 


      i+=1




fr=open("drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/pdb_out.pdb", "r")

print(fr.read())
```